# Can't load the Winter Bash game “Hat Dash”

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

Just now I wanted to play the Hat Dash game, but I can't, it keeps loading, like this:

[image]

I think this is a bug...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be fixed now

> writing a Haiku
> for every single new post
> will be challenging

Comment: It's still not working for me

Comment: What happens if I... oh! They got me. https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/hat-dash/